# Understanding scope of objects in Java. Is there a better way?

Tags: java, class, oop

I think I am missing something.  I want to call a method in an object from a statement in an object of a different class but if I do that the compiler tells me that it cannot find symbol.

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Second secondObj1 = new Second();
        Third thirdObj1= new Third();
        thirdObj1.accessMethodinSecondObj1();
    }
}

class Second
{
    int m1;

    Second()
    {
        m1 = 0;
    }

    public void methodinSecond()
    {
        System.out.println(m1);
    }
}

class Third
{
    void accessMethodinSecondObj1()
    {
        secondObj1.methodinSecond();
    }
}
```

So what I am trying to do is run method `secondObj1.methodinSecond()` from `thirdObj1.accessMethodinSecondObj1()`.  Obviously, this example is a bit silly but it is related to a real problem - but I feel the full code would be too confusing.

I can solve the problem by passing the object reference for `secondObj1` to `thirdObj1` by changing the signature etc., but it seems very convoluted. Maybe there is a better way?

It seems to me that because I declared `secondObj1` in the `main` method then the object itself is only visible within the `main` scope?  Is there no way to allow objects of Second and Third to "talk" to each other directly, meaning call each other's methods?

Comment: second object will not available in Third Class. First declare the Second Class object and try to access it in Third

Comment: Can you clarify what you actually want,
your question looks meesed up

Comment: You need to think abstractly. Each methods needs to have a reference of the objects that it needs to work on. The references can be made by passing in as methods arguments or indirect references which the method knows how to pull. There is no concept of globals in java.

Answer (score 0):

`secondObj1` is a local variable of the `main` method. A local variable is visible only in the block where it's declared. So it's visible only inside the `main` method. Not inside the method `accessMethodinSecondObj1` of `Third`.

If you want this method to access the object referenced by `secondObj1, you need to pass that object as argument to the method:

In main:

```
thirdObj1.accessMethodinSecondObj1(secondObj1);
```

In Third:

```
void accessMethodinSecondObj1(Second s) {
    s.methodinSecond();
}
```

Just like, to print the value of `m1`, you pass `m1` as argument to the method `println()` of `System.out`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler message is about scope, yes.

But there is a more fundmental flaw in your code.  What is you have another Second object and you want to call a method in that one?  Your Third class objects expect any Second class object to be named 'secondObj1'.

You already indicated an solution, change te signature so that the object of class Second you want to access can be passed:

```
 void accessMethodinSecondObj(Second secondObj)
 {
    secondObj.methodinSecond();
 }
```

And then:

```
  thirdObj1.accessMethodinSecondObj(secondObj1);
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  I had already written and tested the way you suggest as indicated in my question. I just wanted to know if there are other options because I believe it will create very difficult to follow code if you don't carefully plan what classes do and how they relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You're along the right lines. You are correct that the scope of `secondObj1` is limited to the `main` method where it is created. So how do we pass `secondObj1` to `thirdObj1`, as they're not globally available?

This first thing to note is that these objects have a relationship. Our class `Third` has a *dependency* upon `Second`. `Third` can't perform its responsibility in `accessMethodinSecondObj1()` without an instance of `Second`. In which case, we have a few options.

Thie simplest of which is to inject the dependency where it is needed. In this case, into the `accessMethodinSecondObj1()` method as such:

```
public class Third
{
    public void accessMethodinSecondObj1(Second secondObj1)
    {
        secondObj1.methodinSecond();
    }
}
```

To call this from `main`, simply:

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Second secondObj1 = new Second();
        Third thirdObj1 = new Third();
        thirdObj1.accessMethodinSecondObj1(secondObj1);
    }
}
```

You could inherit from `Second` as to access its members and methods and call from within `thirdObject1.accessMethodinSecondObj1()` using `super.methodinSecond()`. But as we're dealing in abstractions here, it's a difficult solution to suggest as it may not make semantic sense in your domain.

In which case, another option is [composition](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/uml-aggregation-vs-composition/). We inject an instance of `Second` into `Third` via the constructor and that instance of `Third` then owns that instance of `Second`. By doing so, we ensure `Third` has an instance of `Second` (upon which it depends) when this method is called. This also enables the performing of validation operations on the passed instance of `Second` before we use it in `accessMethodinSecondObj1()`.

```
public class Third
{
    private Second secondObj1; 

    public Third(Second secondObj1)
    {
        this.secondObj1 = secondObj1;
    }

    public void accessMethodinSecondObj1()
    {
        this.secondObj1.methodinSecond();
    }
}
```

In which case, within `main` we would do the following:

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Second secondObj1 = new Second();
        Third thirdObj1 = new Third(secondObj1);

        thirdObj1.accessMethodinSecondObj1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you have confirmed everything I suspected.  I have been coding java for a couple of weeks only but this seems overly complex and restrictive.  I imagine there are very good reasons for designing the language this way but nevertheless it seems to make the code very tangled.

Answer (score -1):

As we can see

```
public void methodinSecond()
{
    System.out.println(m1);
}
```

is not static and therefore in

```
secondObj1.methodinSecond();
```

you cannot call a method without creating an object if it is `non-static`

In your main method

```
Second secondObj = new Second();
```

the scope of the variable would be only inside the block so if you want to use it in the method of `class Third` pass it as a parameter to the method

```
 thirdObj1.accessMethodinSecondObj1(secondObj);
```

and also change the method to

```
void accessMethodinSecondObj1(Second secondObj)
{
    secondObj.methodinSecond();
}
```